# How to add a WCF service reference in a .NET Core 3.1 application?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm attempting to add a WCF service reference to a .Net Core 3.1 web API. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 in admin mode. I get the following error:

```
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of service endpoints found: 1
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Error:Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d <toolname>": C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj
```

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

I've tried installing dotnet-svcutil but I get the following error:

> Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any

Comment: install  dotnet-svcutil    by writing this command ===> Install-Package dotnet-svcutil

Comment: @burg.developer "Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any"

Comment: do you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Jay No, I haven't.

Comment: do you have any alternative solution ? if any than please share.

Comment: Any solution? thx

Answer (score 6):

Dotnet released preview of version 2.0.3. which work with dotnet Core 3.1.
Install it trough package manager console and **reopen** project.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil --version 2.0.3-preview1.20574.1
```

In solution explorer right click on project name -> Add -> Connected Service, should offer Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider

Comment: absolutely good pointer. for latest version refer to the below 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil

Comment: Or use another cmd to create code: dotnet-svcutil http://blablabla/service.svc

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

Open Visual Studio Developer Command prompt and use below command
"*svcutil *.wsdl*" or "*svcutil https://somestire.svc*"

This will create Class file in that specific folder.